# How to Authenticate GET Requests to Firebase Firestore Through the REST API

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I would like to perform authenticated GET requests to Firestore through the REST API. I can successfully perform a GET request when I have my Firestore rules set to:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

The format of the GET request I use for this is as follows:

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/databases/(default)/documents/cities/LA
```

However, if I add authentication and change the rules to:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

I need to be able to authenticate my GET request. I am able to do a POST request under the following format:

```
https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=[API_KEY]&email=[EMAIL]&password=[PASSWORD]
```

This returns an idToken which i want to use to authenticate my GET request.

How do I do this? I have tried adding a KEY to my GET request with the new idToken but I have had no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you get an ID Token, you can pass it to the REST API using an Authorization header with a bearer token:

```
Authorization: Bearer ${idToken}
```

See [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api#authenticating_with_an_access_token) for more information.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering! This worked through postman. I added an Authorization header with Bearer as the idToken.

However, it does not look like it changed the format of the GET request like changing a param would. What does the GET request look like with an Authorization?

Comment: Headers are not included in the URL, they have to be encoded separately. In cURL for instance, you would do `curl --header "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" https://the.url/`. Whatever programming language you're using will certainly have documentation for how to add headers to HTTP requests.

Comment: Great, thank you. Everything is working now as expected.